# Closed G-invariant set in a metric space contained in an open G-invariant set?

Tags: real-analysis, group-actions, ergodic-theory

Let $G$ be a countable discrete group and $X$ a metric space on which $G$ acts continuously and isometrically.  Let $V$ be a closed $G$-invariant set and $U$ be an open $G$-invariant set such that $V \subset U$.  There exists an open set $U^{\prime}$ such that $V \subset U^{\prime} \subset \overline{U^{\prime}} \subset U$ since $X$ is normal.

My question is whether $U^{\prime}$ can be taken to be $G$-invariant.  I've tried various proof attempts and can see how to prove it if $G$ is finite (take the intersection of $gU^{\prime}$ over all $g \in G$ where $U^{\prime}$ is some open set containing $V$) but am unsure if this holds when $G$ is infinite.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you also assume by any chance that the action is isometric? Otherwise the answer is negative.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming the action is isometric.  Will edit to add.

Comment: How about taking the union of the $gU'$?  $\overline{U^{\prime}}$ has a positive distance from $X\setminus U$.  Due to the isometry, all $g\overline{U^{\prime}}$ have this distance from $X\setminus U$, so it seems plausible that the closure of the union will have $\ge$ this distance from $X\setminus U$.

Comment: @ChadK Yes, that works, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an actual proof. We have two disjoint closed $G$-invariant subsets of $X$: $V$ and $U^c=X\setminus U$. The functions $f, h: X\to {\mathbb R}$, $f(x)=d(x, V)$, $h(x)=d(x, U^c)$ are continuous and $G$-invariant. Define
$$
U'= \left\{ x: f(x) - h(x)< 0 \right\}.
$$
This is an open $G$-invariant subset containing $V$. Its closure is contained in
$$
\left\{x: f(x) - h(x)\le 0\right\},
$$
which is disjoint from $U^c$. Hence, $cl(U')\subset U$.

Comment: Thank you, this is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to ChadK for the help.

Let $U^{\prime}$ be any open set containing $V$ such that $\overline{U^{\prime}} \subseteq U$.  Then $V = gV \subseteq gU^{\prime}$ for all $g$.  Since $G$ acts isometrically, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $d(U^{\prime},U^{C}) > \delta$.  Then $d(gU^{\prime},U^{C}) = d(gU^{\prime},gU^{C}) = d(U^{\prime},U^{C}) > \delta$ so $d(\cup gU^{\prime},U^{C}) > \delta$.  Set $U_{0} = \cup gU^{\prime}$.  Then $U_{0}$ is open and $G$-invariant.  Since $d(U_{0},U^{C}) > \delta$, then $d(\overline{U_{0}},U^{C}) \geq \delta$.  Therefore $V \subseteq U_{0} \subseteq \overline{U_{0}} \subseteq U$.

Comment: The 3rd sentence in this proof is wrong. I stopped reading after that. (The mistake can be blamed on Chad's suggestion...)

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am certain you are correct but not seeing why.  If $d(V_n, V) > \delta$ for some sets $V_{n}$ and $V$ then does it not follow that $d(\cup V_{n},V) > \delta$?

Comment: Chad is wrong when he assumes that $d(U', U^c)>0$.